# When will the object in swift be deleted?

Tags: ios, swift, object

I am a new Swift learner. Now I am really confused about the deallocation of the Swift objects. For example, I created a `UIView` object in `viewDidload()` method and add it to the main view. I think the view created by me should be destroyed directly after the calling of method `viewDidload()` , Cause it is a local variable.

But I can still see this view on the screen which makes me very confused. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: _...I can still see this view on the screenShow_,  show your code, please

Comment: Hi, I mean this view is surely still on the screen, so that it makes me confused. But now I understand it much better by reading something about ARC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add your view to the main view, what happened behind the scenes is the main view took 'ownership' of your view by you giving it a strong reference to it. That is why it is still showing on the screen, and has not been deallocated.

Check out this guide in the Swift Docs to understand more about ARC.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID49

Comment: hi, you helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Object lifetime is controlled using references. If you add the view to another view, its still referenced by that view, as a subview.

Removing that subview from the view, e.g. someView.removeFromSuperView() will remove that reference, although you will need the original reference to do that :/

Why do you want the view to be destroyed, but still visible?

Answer (score 1):

You have added view to the view controller's view so it retain count is 1 (which is greater that 0 so this object won't be deallocated). If you don't remove your view from superview manually, it will be deallocated during superview deallocation.